# Unable to set text in a Text View

Tags: android

I have a strange problem using Android Studio. I can't set the text of a TextView (tAx), the reference isn't a 'null pointer', and I haven't error or exception, just I don't see the text.

My main class:

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,   R.layout.custom_title);


    tAx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Ax);
    tAx.setText("prova");
    // Set up the custom title
    mTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_left_text);
  //  mTitle.setText(R.string.app_name);
    mTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_right_text);

    // Get local Bluetooth adapter
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    // If the adapter is null, then Bluetooth is not supported
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available",         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
        return;
    }
}
```

XML Main :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:weightSum="1">

<TextView android:id="@+id/Ax"
    android:layout_width="198dp"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    android:textColor="#fff"
 />


</LinearLayout>
```

Thank's you!

Update:

Thank's you! So now I can set the text but only one time(the first time)! In another class, I try to set the text by reference (using tax reference that is static and public), but them doesn't change, but remains the first, and Android Studio print on the console the error:

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its
>   views

`RemoteBluetooth.tAx.setText(String.valueOf(Ax));`

Comment: Is that ALL of your layout's XML?

Comment: call setContentView after calling super.onCreate

Comment: Yes it's all my layout's xml. I start now using Android.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably fix your error by using an id starting with a lowercase letter. Android seems to have a problem with id's starting with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

Remove   `android:weightSum="1"`

and check the rest of your `xml` files, because this occurs when you have a syntax error in your `xml` files.

Answer (score 0):

You are just plotting it white on white. Change the `textColor` attribute to something else.

Comment: Thank's you! So now i can set the text only one time! In another class, I try to set the text by reference (using tAx that is static and public), but them doesn't change, but remains the first! Can you help me? Thank's.
`RemoteBluetooth.tAx.setText(String.valueOf(Ax));`

Comment: Judging by the error you posted, it looks like you cannot. Views updating should be managed only from the UI thread - looks like you are trying to setText from another thread. This might be material for a new question, but I guess this kind of issue has already an answer somewhere here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You set the background and the text color with the same color value, of curse you can't see any change.

Change the color of text to a color different with the background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Ax"
        android:layout_width="198dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>
```